# C# change Intellisense info

Tags: c#, intellisense

I have a member of some class that definition is Like:

```
public static object CallMethod(Type oType, String sMethodName, params object [] paramenters)
{
    /* some code exist here, not required in this scenario */

    CarrierContainer cc = new CarrierContainer();
    CarrierContainer.SetMethod.SetServiceAndFunction(cc, oType.Name.Substring(1), sMethodName);

    foreach (object item in paramenters) {  cc.Params.Add(item); }

    object obj = WCFClient.ExecuteService(cc);
    return obj;
}
```

and my calling part is like:

```
return (ID)WCFServiceClient.CallMethod(ServiceType, "Save", this);
```

now my point is while I have completed type:

```
return (ID)WCFServiceClient.CallMethod(ServiceType, "Save",
```

i don't know how many parameters are required for "Save" and i want to show IntelliSense info while typing based on two parameters typed *ServiceType, "Save"*.

Please anyone have suggestion about control IntelliSense info while typing some code in C# editor?

Comment: Use [XML documentation comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). Just start typing `///` and the IDE will do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The explicit definition of the method claims:

> I don't know *exactly* how many parameters can be in that array

So what you expect from the IntelliSense is not what defined in the code.
If you want IntelliSense help you, you should explicitly define parameters in function definition.

Other "solution" could be use of the comments in appropriate way.

Comment: definitely i have defined parameter set in Interface (that is 'ServiceType') definition, please see below the code:  
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBankService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Bank Get(ID id);
        [OperationContract]
        bool Delete(ID oID);
        [OperationContract]
        ID Save(Bank oBank);
    }  
but while i am typing that time different method may have different set of params....